# Is the integrity of the Conda packages verified?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda, package-managers

When installing a package using `conda install <some package>` or `conda install -c <some channel> <some package>`, does the `conda` binary verify the integrity of the downloaded package archive (using algorithms such as SHA256)?

The reason I ask is that, in some countries, the official Anaconda Cloud repository is very slow (or blocked), and a local mirror is often faster and provides a better user experience, but the integrity of the local mirror is not guaranteed. If the `conda` binary somehow verifies the downloaded archive using metadata obtained from the official Anaconda Cloud repository, then those less fortunate users could still use the local mirror and not have to worry about the integrity of the local mirror.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No Independent Metadata (AFAIK)

Conda does have an option for SHA256 integrity checking (`conda config --set extra_safety_checks true`), but it's not for the problem you are trying to solve. The issue is that the checksum info is provided in the package archive itself, in the `info/paths.json` file, not by an independent metadata repository. This might mitigate against a middleman inserting something into an archive file, but it won't catch a package that has been built with `conda build` to include malicious code and pushed to a channel. Hence, it is important to **use only trusted channels.**

#### Why the Safety Checks, Then?

Aside from basic file integrity verification, the primary use case for the checks that are provided is actually to prevent Conda from being surprised by Pip clobbering its package files. Since Conda uses hardlinks, if Pip writes over a package file in one env, it is writing over it in potentially all future envs. While it won't catch Pip in the act, these safety checks at least have Conda check to make sure that the package is still intact before linking it into another env.

There's a little background in the ["*Understanding and Improving Conda's Performance*"](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance/) post, under the *Verifying package contents* section.